# JSlider#setLabelTable, labels make the track narrower

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm having a annoying issue when calling [JSlider#setLabelTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setLabelTable%28java.util.Dictionary%29) with descriptive labels. The problem is that the track (that usually goes from side to side using all of the sliders width) gets narrowed because of the length of the labels.

By default the slider looks like:

```
##############################################
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
```

But with custom labels it looks something like this:

```
     ############################
     |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
Low priority     High priority (Quick delivery)
```

But I want something like this:

```
##############################################
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
Low priority                                 High priority (Quick delivery)
```

Anyone know if this is possible?
I'm afraid this involves [BasicSliderUI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicSliderUI.html) which unfortunately isn't an option since the application supports multiple L&Fs.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) showing my problem:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JSliderLabelTableProblem
{
    public JSliderLabelTableProblem()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setBounds(new Rectangle(200, 200, 400, 200));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createNormalSlider(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(createSliderWithLabels(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JSlider createNormalSlider()
    {
        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.setMinimum(1);
        slider.setMaximum(10);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        return slider;
    }

    private JSlider createSliderWithLabels()
    {
        JSlider slider = createNormalSlider();
        Dictionary<Integer, JComponent> labels = new Hashtable<Integer, JComponent>();
        labels.put(1, new JLabel("Low priority"));
        labels.put(10, new JLabel("High priority (Quick delivery)"));
        slider.setLabelTable(labels);
        return slider;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new JSliderLabelTableProblem();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can [*Use HTML in Swing Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html), you might try wrapping the labels to fit better.

```
labels.put(1, new JLabel("<html>Low<br>priority</html>"));
labels.put(10, new JLabel("<html>High priority<br>(Quick delivery)</html>"));
```

Addendum: You also might try altering the label's horizontal alignment.

Addendum: Another approach might be to use short labels on the slider itself and add an explanatory legend nearby. If you have to implelent a custom component, I found Kirill Grouchnikov's [*How to Write a Custom Swing Component*](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html) helpful.

Comment: I tried that before posting - didn't work... But now I see that it indeed works, problem was that I was using SubstanceL&F that for some reason doesn't render HTML properly (though it reserve extra space because of line breaks). This wasn't exactly what I wanted but I'll accept your answer because it seems to be the best option there is.

Comment: It's a compromise; I've added more above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to make your own version of JSlider and override method
`public Hashtable createStandardLabels( int increment, int start )`
where specially this line is ready for changes
`put( new Integer  ( labelIndex ), new LabelUIResource( ""+labelIndex, JLabel.CENTER ) );`

according to code found at:
http://kickjava.com/src/javax/swing/JSlider.java.htm

Comment: No that doesn't seem to make any difference. After some more digging I see now that the "layout" and painting of the JSlider is performed by BasicSliderUI, creating a custom UI class and overriding #paintHorizontalLabel changes position of the labels but then everything else needs to be modified as well... Seems this problem is too hard to solve in a reasonable way :(

Comment: i haven't said it would be simple. I just offered you an option. Little bit similar to second one from @trashgod. And override method of class which is fully opensource and documented isn't very tough. Take it easy :)